# Public localhost - possible?

Tags: dns, ip, localhost, external, public

Is it possible to make my localhost to be available to everyone?, under a certain domain?

(**Without external ip**)

I will be grateful if someone describe it **step by step**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, but a lot of it depends upon your local network and your Internet Service provider:

- Ideally, you would have a static IP address from your ISP. There are workarounds using external dynamic DNS services (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS), but as I say they are workarounds rather than proper solutions.
- If you want it under your own domain, the dynamic DNS provider may support this, either directly or by providing you with a hostname you can add a CNAME to in your own domain's dns settings. If you do have a static IP address, that can be added as an 'A' record instead.
- You would have to ensure that your ISP allows connections to port 80 from external sources. You would have to ask your ISP about this, though; some may not, to discourage people from doing exactly what you're trying to do.
- Your local firewall / router will need to know to route port 80 to your local machine; the steps for this would depend upon the model of router you're using.

In all, unless you know what you're doing, it's generally worthwhile spending a few pennies and using a 'proper' hosting solution.